# Is it possible to extract angles from the skeletal tracking for all the joints?

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

is it possible to extract the angles of the skeleton ?

If it is possible anybody has sample code to guide me through?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mathematical problem. You may have better luck with this question at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but you need to ask it properly.
The kinect-sdk gives joint locations in 3D space, so you just need the angle between 3 points in 3D space. The position of the head joint using the kinect-sdk, for example, is found like this:

```
Skeleton skeleton;
...
var head = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position;
```

See [Skeletal Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973074.aspx) and [JointType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointtype.aspx).